# JavaScript - Object from two array (parent and child elements)

Tags: javascript

**I have 2 Arrays:**

```
var links = [
  {
    code: 'home'
  },
  {
    code: 'contact'
  },
];

var subLinks = [
  {
    code: 'some subLink',
    parent: {
      code: 'home'
    }
  },
  {
    code: 'some subLink 2',
    parent: {
      code: 'home'
    }
  },
  {
    code: 'some subLink 3',
    parent: {
      code: 'contact'
    }
  }
];
```

**I need to have Object** (link as key with array of subLinks):

```
var menu = {
  home: ["some subLink", "some subLink 2"],
  contact: ["some subLink 3"]
};
```

At this moment I have this...

```
links.map(link => ({
    [link.code]: subLinks.map(subLink => (subLink.parent.code === link.code && subLink.code))
}))
```

Comment: `map` will return an array. Consider using `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

I absolutely love array transformations using functional JS...

```
const menu = {};

links.map(link => menu[link.code] = subLinks
    .filter(sl => sl.parent.code === link.code)
    .map(sl => sl.code)
);
```

Using reduce...

```
const menu = links.reduce((memo, menu) => {
    memo[menu.code] = subLinks
        .filter(sl => sl.parent.code === menu.code)
        .map(sl => sl.code);
    return memo;
},{});
```

Both are pretty sweet, but reduce not having to create a variable to mutate inside the loops might just be a little sweeter.

Comment: Note that this fully iterates `subLinks` exactly `links.length` times.

Comment: There wasnt any spec of O notation ;)

Comment: It wasn’t meant as criticism, just a friendly note ;) I still like your code! :D

Comment: Not taken as criticism! :) I find most readable code is usually the best - deal with any O stuff as it comes. Sometime arrays are just smallish and it wont matter we are making more iterations than actually required.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var links = [
  { code: 'home' },
  { code: 'contact' },
];
var subLinks = [
  { code: 'some subLink', parent: { code: 'home' } },
  { code: 'some subLink 2', parent: { code: 'home' } },
  { code: 'some subLink 3', parent: { code: 'contact' } }
];
var menu={};

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    var code = links[i].code;
    menu[code]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<subLinks.length;j++){
        var subLink = subLinks[j];
        if(subLink.parent && subLink.parent.code == code){
             menu[code].push(subLink.code);
        }
    }
}
console.log(menu)
```

Comment: Note that this fully iterates `subLinks` exactly `links.length` times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two passes: First, you iterate your `links` to create the base object with your parent links. Then, you iterate your `subLinks` to add them to the respective link that you added in the first pass.

This has the benefit that it explicitly only iterates each of your original arrays *once*.

```js
var links = [
  { code: 'home' },
  { code: 'contact' },
];
var subLinks = [
  { code: 'some subLink', parent: { code: 'home' } },
  { code: 'some subLink 2', parent: { code: 'home' } },
  { code: 'some subLink 3', parent: { code: 'contact' } }
];

// pass 1
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  result[links[i].code] = [];
}

// pass 2
for (var i = 0; i < subLinks.length; i++) {
  var subLink = subLinks[i];
  result[subLink.parent.code].push(subLink.code);
}

console.log(result);
```

Note that in your example, you do not explicitly need to have `links`. You can also construct the parent link *on demand* whenever you encounter a sub link with a parent that does not exist yet.

But having this separately allows you to expand your structure to include other information as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = subLinks.reduce((c, v) => {
    if(c.hasOwnProperty(v.parent.code)) c[v.parent.code].push(v.code);
    else c[v.parent.code] = [v.code];
    return c; 
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

A double loop will do :

```js
var links = [
  {
 code: 'home'
  },
  {
 code: 'contact'
  },
];

var subLinks = [
  {
 code: 'some subLink',
 parent: {
   code: 'home'
 }
  },
  {
 code: 'some subLink 2',
 parent: {
   code: 'home'
 }
  },
  {
 code: 'some subLink 3',
 parent: {
   code: 'contact'
 }
  }
];
var menu = {};

for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
var prop = links[i].code;
var child;
 menu[prop]=[];
 for(var j=0;j<subLinks.length;j++){
  var parent = subLinks[j].parent.code;
  if(parent==prop){
   child = subLinks[j].code;
   menu[prop].push(child);
  } 
 }
}


console.log(menu);
```

Comment: Thanks Werner, it's better that way

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```js
var links = [{
  code: 'home'
}, {
  code: 'contact'
}];

var subLinks = [{
  code: 'some subLink',
  parent: {
    code: 'home'
  }
}, {
  code: 'some subLink 2',
  parent: {
    code: 'home'
  }
}, {
  code: 'some subLink 3',
  parent: {
    code: 'contact'
  }
}];

const result = links.reduce((o, x) => {
  o[x.code] = subLinks.filter(f => f.parent.code == x.code).map(m => m.code);
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Documentations:

- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b)
- [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** you can also use something like this: 
here salesInvoice(parent) can have multiple salesInvoiceItems(child) **/

const salesInvoices = [{
        id: 1,
        invoice_no: 'inv1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        invoice_no: 'inv2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        invoice_no: 'inv3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        invoice_no: 'inv4'
    },
]

const salesInvoiceItems = [{
        id: 1,
        sales_invoice_id: 1,
        name: 'inv1item'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        sales_invoice_id: 1,
        name: 'inv1item'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        sales_invoice_id: 2,
        name: 'inv2item'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        sales_invoice_id: 2,
        name: 'inv2item'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        sales_invoice_id: 2,
        name: 'inv2item'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        sales_invoice_id: 2,
        name: 'inv2item'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        sales_invoice_id: 2,
        name: 'inv2item'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        sales_invoice_id: 3,
        name: 'inv3item'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        sales_invoice_id: 3,
        name: 'inv3item'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        sales_invoice_id: 3,
        name: 'inv3item'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        sales_invoice_id: 3,
        name: 'inv3item'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        sales_invoice_id: 3,
        name: 'inv3item'
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        sales_invoice_id: 4,
        name: 'inv4item'
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        sales_invoice_id: 4,
        name: 'inv4item'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        sales_invoice_id: 4,
        name: 'inv4item'
    },
]


for (let singleItem of salesInvoices) {
    const InvoiceItems = salesInvoiceItems.filter(item => item.sales_invoice_id == singleItem.id);
    singleItem.salesInvoiceItemList = InvoiceItems;
}
```

console.log(salesInvoices)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).